# Bootstrap CDN does not work in IE8

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

I am trying to publish my website using Bootstrap CDN and want it to work correctly in IE8.
However, when referencing the Bootstrap CSS on my web server, Bootstrap works perfectly but, when using CDN, the layout of the page will break.

The following brief example hosted on my web server works correctly in IE8 emulation mode on IE11.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>brief example</title>
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          left side
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          right side
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`bootstrap.min.css` is the file downloaded from https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css.

However, replacing `bootstrap.min.css` to `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css` makes the layout broken.
"right side" gets placed on the bottom side of "left side".

What causes the problem?

Comment: Have you made any edits to the looks of your site? If so, have you edited the `bootstrap.css`, on your computer, directly or have you made a custom (or internal) stylesheet changing the looks of Bootstrap? Also, are you using the same version of Bootstrap on your computer as the CDN, vice versa?

Comment: Did you upload the bootstrap.css in the same directrory where your posted HTML is? If not you are referencing to a file which do not exist in the given location. Also as @JoshMurray say you need to upload the same version you have used while developing your site.

Comment: I have not made any changes.
The content of `bootstrap.min.css` is equal to the content of `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css`.
Therefore, I think the problem is not the version mismatch.
`bootstrap.min.css` and the example HTML are in the same directory.

Comment: Are all files loaded? You can use fiddler to see if any file gives a http-404 response

Comment: According to F12 Developer Tools of IE11, all files including Bootstrap CDN give 200 responses.

Comment: In your HTML document, are you placing `<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` AND `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`?

Comment: So what you are saying is that you want a page to work correctly on a browser that Microsoft will no longer support in less then a month? Seems like a legit question... https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith: Just because Microsoft are going to stop supporting their beloved Internet Explorer, doesn't mean people won't download more recent/popular browsers such as Firefox, Chrome or Safari.

Comment: @JoshMurray what sense does your comment make? If someone downloads Firefox/Chrome or Safari they will not have the ie8 problem anymore will they?

Comment: Sorry, meant to say: "doesn't mean people *will* download more recent/popular".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What caused the problem is the limitation of respond.js.
According to [README of respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/tree/1.4.2#cdnx-domain-setup), respond.js can not parse stylesheets hosted on CDNs by default.
So, adding codes is required.
The following is the example working correctly in IE8.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>brief example</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/respond-proxy.html" id="respond-proxy" rel="respond-proxy" />
      <link href="respond.proxy.gif" id="respond-redirect" rel="respond-redirect" />
      <script src="respond.proxy.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          left side
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          right side
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`respond.proxy.gif` is the file downloaded from `https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/raw/1.4.2/cross-domain/respond.proxy.gif`.
`respond.proxy.js` is the file downloaded from `https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/raw/1.4.2/cross-domain/respond.proxy.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Use

```
//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

(omit the "https:")

Comment: This still works even if there is a *https:* at the start of the `href`.

Comment: The layout was still broken.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is not problem. Try to run your project from any server. like `localhost` or `webserver`. I prefer to use `webserver`. May be problem will be solved.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. I checked the layout of the page from http://(my-web-server)/. I edited my post for more clarification.