# Seeing diff results between IE and Chrome in app layout

Tags: html, apache, internet-explorer, alignment, react-bootstrap

I have a reactjs app and am using the below CDN's to get my styling ... The app is being hosted by Apache

```
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

In Chrome my app looks nice and clean ... everything lines up but in IE it looks terrible ... it is all squished in to the middle of the page .... Anyone ever seen this before ?

Comment: Which version of IE you are using? If you are using IE 8 than it requires the use of Respond.js to enable media query support. you can find in the documentation that some other features are also not supported for IE 8. Ref: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#support-ie8-ie9 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34320921/bootstrap-cdn-does-not-work-in-ie8

Comment: I am using IE 11

Comment: You can try to post your sample code and output images. We will try to test your code with IE 11 and try to produce the issue. Than we can try to find any possible solution for it.